# Carousel/Pagination with <apex:repeat>?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, pagination

I have an  element that gets records from my object (custom object Banker_details__c, the field is a rich text area Banker_photo__c which contains just an image) and displays a radio button + its clickable label (the image from before is displayed in here.

I have multiple records (about 30) and I wish to ONLY display 5 at a time (because 30 records takes too much space).

I've searched about the methods I could use and I've found about PAGINATION and CAROUSEL.

[Carousel with multiple slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558936/modify-bootstrap-carousel-to-display-multiple-slides-simultaneously)

I'd prefer to use a CAROUSEL, since PAGINATION (afaik) reloads the page. I donot want that to happen.

So, is it possible to :

1. Have a "dynamic" carousel with ?
2. Be able to associate the carousel's slides/images with radio buttons?

What I've tried till now :

[as usual, spectacular failure](http://codepad.org/hRTqYF7i)

It simply makes each individual element have its own arrows (ie, it makes each element behave like a carousel).

I have a feeling that I am trying to bite off more than I can chew.

Comment: Don't think there is a reason it shouldn't work. Comparing your code with this [Carousel Example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp), you are missing `data-ride="carousel"` and I'd leave off the `active`. Suggest you paste that example into your VF and make sure it works then use your browser's "View Source" on the `apex:repeat` output and compare/adjust. To hold the selection of radio buttons you would need to use [Wrapper Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class).

Comment: Ok will try this way. Though on the W3Schools site, it mentioned that ATLEAST one element should have `active` else code wont work.

Comment: Glad you are reading more carefully than I am...